# How do I delete entites that contain a certain property in NDB model?

Tags: python, app-engine-ndb

I have this set up:

```py
class ImageInfo(ndb.Model):
    location=ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    level=ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    image_url= ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
    url= ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
    description=ndb.StringProperty(required=False)
    scalewidth= ndb.IntegerProperty(required=False)
    scaleheight= ndb.IntegerProperty(required=False)
    pointer=ndb.BooleanProperty(required=False,default=False)
    pointerlocation=ndb.IntegerProperty(required=False)
    pointerlist=ndb.IntegerProperty(required=False,repeated=True)

ANCESTORY_KEY = ndb.Key("ImageInfo","ImageInfo_root")
```

and I want to delete everything that contains the property: level==2.
I searched through the google documentation, but it asks for keys and I have no idea what they are. 
I am assuming that here, I do something like:

```py
def test():
    ImageInfo.level==2.delete()
#syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

oh, why do I always find the answer 5 seconds after posting the question

```py
def test():
    img=ImageInfo.query(ImageInfo.level==2).fetch()
    for i in img:
        i.key.delete()
#this will clear every entity with the property: level==2
#if you get a out of bound error, then it is probably because you forgot the img[0]
```